# GLFW window becomes unresponsive when asking for input!

Tags: c++, glfw

I am trying to write a simple C++ game using OpenGL. In my render loop i ask for text based input from the user but this causes the GLFW window to become unresponsive. I suspect that this happens because the window does not like it when the main thread is paused from std::cin so it behaves weirdly. If i remove the input prompt the window behaves perfectly. Can someone confirm if this is the case and what workarounds are there to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Your program is waiting for the user to give their input before continuing.

The workaround to this is to use [asynchronous input](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O).

An example of this in GLFW is to use something like this:

`// Set the callback
glfwSetKeyCallback(g_odin.windowManager.g_window, key_callback);

// The function that gets called on key events 
void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) { /* ... do something ... */ }`